# Given a string S and a set of words D, find the longest word in D that is a subsequence of S

Tags: python

I tried solving this in python 2.7 using **regex**. I found it to be quite simple. Wondering if I am missing something. Is there an edge case or corner case here?

```
S = "abppplee"
D = {"able", "ale", "apple", "bale", "kangaroo"}

def subseq(S,D):  
    # every word in D is made into a regex pattern interspersed with .* and looked up in S
    import re
    in_dict = {word:len(word) for word in D if bool(re.search(pattern=".*".join(word),string=S))}
    return max(in_dict, key=in_dict.get)

subseq(S,D)
```

returns 'apple'

Comment: This question is on topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It won't work if one of the words contains special regex characters like `.` or `*` or `+` or `$` or `(` or `[` or `{`.

Answer (score 0):

### **re.search**

Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning a match object, or None if no match was found.

---

But in your case you need to find the **subsequence** of string with list.
Code for generating subsequence is

---

```
def subsequence(X, Y, m, n):
    L = [[0 for x in range(n + 1)] for x in range(m + 1)]

    # Following steps build L[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. Note
    # that L[i][j] contains length of LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1]
    for i in range(m + 1):
        for j in range(n + 1):
            if i == 0 or j == 0:
                L[i][j] = 0
            elif X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]:
                L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
            else:
                L[i][j] = max(L[i - 1][j], L[i][j - 1])

    # Following code is used to print LCS
    val = L[m][n]
    index = L[m][n]

    # Create a character array to store the lcs string
    lcs = [""] * (index + 1)
    lcs[index] = "\0"

    # Start from the right-most-bottom-most corner and
    # one by one store characters in lcs[]
    i = m
    j = n
    while i > 0 and j > 0:

        # If current character in X[] and Y are same, then
        # current character is part of LCS
        if X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]:
            lcs[index - 1] = X[i - 1]
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
            index -= 1

        # If not same, then find the larger of two and
        # go in the direction of larger value
        elif L[i - 1][j] > L[i][j - 1]:
            i -= 1
        else:
            j -= 1

    sequence = "".join(lcs)
    return val,sequence

#Driver Code
S = "alnegearoo"
D = {"able", "ale", "apple", "bale", "kangaroo"}
max_len = 0
max_string = ""
for word in D:
    subseq_len,match = subsequence(word,S,len(word),len(S))
    if(max_len < subseq_len):
        max_len = subseq_len
        max_string = match

print(max_string)
```

---

### Output

angaroo

Enjoy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

I did it using java hopefully it can help others to solve it

```
public String lookFor(String inputWord, String[] dictionary) {

  Arrays.sort(dictionary);

  for (int index = dictionary.length - 1; index > 0; index--) {
    if (isTheWordASubsequence(inputWord, dictionary[index]))
      return dictionary[index];
  }

  return null;
}

private boolean isTheWordASubsequence(String inputWord,
    String dictionaryWord) {

  int spot = 0;
  int offset = 0;

  for (char item : dictionaryWord.toCharArray()) {
    spot = (offset = inputWord.indexOf(item, spot)) >= spot ? offset : -1;
    if (spot < 0)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `re.escape`.

```py
import re
string = 'abppplee{lkfj3lkj.f*)(*)(*@}dddd.sdf*3j3jj3}@@@@'
words = {'apple', 'ale', 'bale', 'able', 'apple{}.*', 'kangaroo'}
max({word for word in words
     if re.search('.*'.join(map(re.escape, word)), string)},
    key=len)
```

I hardly differentiate between answering this question and doing Kata on e.g. [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/).